# Routing traffic to network printer via a specific interface

Tags: networking, printing

I have a Linux machine with `eth0` for my router-modem and I want to add a second interface `eth1` to connect to my Apple LaserWriter printer.

Everything is on `192.168.1.x`:

- My address IP is `192.168.1.2`.
- My router (`default gw`) IP is `192.168.1.1`.
- My printer IP is `192.168.1.100`.

What should I do to route traffic to the printer. Is adding a static route all there is to it?

Would this work?

```
route add -host 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1
```

What about determining the correct netmask if the above one is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'd put the printer on a separate subnet then this will happen automatically.  For example, make the printer 192.168.2.100/24 and your machine's eth1 192.168.2.2/24.